# Управление перезагрузкой по USB

Tags: usb

Специфика моей работы часто требует перезагрузить или выключить ПК дистанционно, желательно - с помощью ФИЗИЧЕСКОЙ кнопки. Единственный доступный порт - USB. Буду очень благодарен за схему нужного контроллера или ссылку на неё. В схемотехнике разбираюсь, с паяльником на "ты". С программированием сложнее...

Comment: ну дак чтобы сделать power-cycle, то и управлять надо не писюком, а системой контроля питания

Comment: Это реально сделать через USB? Если подскажете, как ИМЕННО, буду очень благодарен...

Answer (score 1):

Нашел только [такую штуку](http://chinawebshop.ru/product_37689.html).

Фраза "кирпич на газ" Вам теперь не будет казаться такой смешной.

Если хотите сделать сами, то, думаю, вам стоит с таким вопросом обратиться на `cxem.net`. Возможно, там Вам смогут помочь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это ИМЕННО то, что нужно! Не думал, что такие гаджеты выпускаются. Немного смущает стоимость доставки из Китая - 450 р., но если на "Ali.com" дешевле не найду, то куплю без раздумий! Ещё раз спасибо!!!

Comment: Я надеюсь, что Вам нужно перезагружаться при загруженной системе, ибо при BSOD'е и т.п. такой гаджет вряд ли поможет.

Comment: И что это за штука? Там срок регистрации домена закончился.

Comment: Насколько помню - там был usb выключатель компа по типу кнопки у стоматологов для включения бор-машинки. Попробуйте через webarchive глянуть. Сделал для вас скрин: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhH4Al5XdPZGhr1XrClywv3XtzTr2g?e=IGGLZq

Answer (score 1):

КТ315 + Arduino + Ethernet Shield + if NAT (DynDNS + Port_forvarding).

Принцип действия:

Подключаете замыкатель к кнопке перезагрузки и делаете простую веб страницу, на которой расположена кнопка. Далее настраиваете НАТ (если нужно) и получаете доступ к перезагрузке везде, где есть интернет.

Как сделать замыкатель: http://cxem.net/radiomic/radiomic131.php

Как управлять через ардуину: http://robocraft.ru/blog/arduino/203.html

Немного дороговато получается, но все понятно и нужен минимум знаний.